# "...as stated by its atheistic leaders more than 30 years ago" in McCarthy speech

Tags: communism

I read this quote in a [speech](http://teachingamericanhistory.org/library/document/speech-explaining-the-communist-threat/) given on June 2, 1950 by Joseph McCarthy that said:

> "We know that the major aim of communism, as stated by its atheistic leaders more than 30 years ago, is to create a Red China, thence a Red Asia, wash it with a Red Pacific - and then enslave America."

Is there a speech by a Communist leader that insinuates this goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insofar as the [Marxist view of history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marxist_historiography) holds that class revolution is inevitable and inexorable, this was expected to [spread around the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_revolution). As such, [exporting revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_revolution) was a major goal of Communist powers. Lenin was [the champion of world revolution](https://www.encyclopedia.com/history/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/world-revolution) and founded the prominent umbrella group, the "[Communist International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_International)", in 1919.

In your question, the notoriously [anti-red](http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/hi/dates/stories/february/9/newsid_3703000/3703305.stm) Senator Joseph McCarthy seems to have simply added some color to the story by describing the revolutionary process as "enslavement".

Comment: given that the population at large under communist regimes are slaves to their governments, the term was and still is quite appropriate.

Comment: While Marxist theories predicted the inevitable demise of capitalism, this inevitability prevented communist powers from doing nothing - they just had to wait. McCarthy, being the paranoid he was, was denouncing a tinfoil-hat conspiracy theory as it was a fact. Remember the man was mad as a hat, and worst of it, a politician. Why would he say anything factual?

Comment: Besides the controversial vocabulary *revolutionary process* vs *enslavement*, is there any statement by Communist leaders hinting about such a sequential and eastern spread of Communism (Russia->China->Asia->Pacific->America) rather than a more holistic (revolution everywhere at once!)  or western (*free* the European working class!) agenda, that MacCarthy might have been refering to ?

Comment: @Rekesoft to be fair, despite *Das Kapital* assurances, the Soviet Union was not prevented from acting whenever it could (e.g. Eastern Europe, Afghanistan ) in order to keep and maintain its sphere of influence. There is some discussion about it being a defensive strategy (create a buffer to prevent another invasion) but it did certainly did take some measures other than waiting for the West to collapse).

Comment: @Evargalo Good point. It is worth remembering that Stalin did initially support Chiang Kai Check and did ignore Communist movements in China (Operation Zet) and that the support switched when Chiang protested the annexation of Tannu Tuva.

Comment: @SJuan76 : it is a bit more complicated (nicer paper here, in PDF: src-h.slav.hokudai.ac.jp/rp/publications/no09/09_08_Radchenko.pdf) but true, Stalin's Asian politics didn't change much compared to tsarist Russia: creating buffer states, containing of England and Japan, gaining influence in China, accessing ressources..., and it was built on much more *realpolitik* than ideology. Statements that we should be looking for, "30 years before MacCarthy", would predate Stalin's rise to power, but I didn't find anything circa 1920.

Comment: @Rekesoft: Perhaps in theory all the Communist powers would have had to do was wait, but the fact of history is that this is NOT what they actually did.  E.g. USSR occupying eastern Europe, USSR & PRC supporting Communist movements in Asia & South America, &c, USSR-supported Communist party in the US: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_Party_USA#Soviet_funding_and_espionage  The Communist conspiracy was real: McCarthy's personal failings & often-unsupported accusations probably did more to obscure this than expose it.

Comment: @SJuan76 While it's true that any socialist revolutionary could call the USSR for help, I fail to see an organized plan to take over the world. After all, the US didn't lose any opportunity to facilitate fascist regimes in central and south America, promoting terrorism in Italy or provoking a civil war in Greece. It's that a proof of a *"major aim, as stated by it's fundamentalistic zealot leaders more than a century ago (Monroe doctrine), to create a blue America, then a blue Europe, wash it with a blue Atlantic, then slaving Russia?"*

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. I doubt very much if any communist leader would be stupid enough to openly say they want to enslave anyone. America enslaves, of course. But not the other way around. Communism liberates people. *(Not my opinion - theirs.)*

Comment: Thanks! Been working on Rhetorical analysis.

Comment: freedom is slavery. war is peace...

Comment: @jwenting 1984 was a novel. Not a #$%$# manual! :-)

Comment: I think that even people who took MacCarthy's words for truth understood that he was not quoting Communist/Atheist leaders litterally. To answer this question, we should look for Communist statements about *liberating* China, Asia, Pacific and then America.